# Vue 3 - tree - change to JSON text not reflected in tree

Tags: vuejs3

Newbie question, just getting into Vue 3, using https://github.com/wopehq/vue3-tree but I think my question deals more with basic reactivity, I added the bottom 2 lines to the onNodeClick method:

```
const onNodeClick = (node) => {
  console.log(node);
  node.label = "Label got changed!!!";
  console.log("Label got changed???");
};
```

The label doesn't get changed in the tree - I've tried using Vue.set(...) but that is not available in Vue 3, so what do I use?

https://4b465s.csb.app/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to check the source code.

Turns out there is  the use-ready function `updateNode()` in the library.

You just have to make a `ref` to the `Tree.vue` component ([Vue Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs)) like this:

```
 <Tree ref="tree"
```

and declare it in the `setup()`

```
const tree = ref(null);
... 
return {
   nodes,
   tree,
```

Then you can simply use the `updateNode()` function like this:

```
  //node.label = "Label got changed!!!";      
  tree.value.updateNode(node.id, { label:  "Label got changed!!!" });
```

Check your [updated playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-tree-demo-forked-vxzxpw?file=/src/App.vue:2967-3069)

The library update functions seems to have a glitch. The first nodes in the tree are not updating with the `updateNode()` function.

Check the [vue3-tree/src/lib/utils/](https://github.com/wopehq/vue3-tree/tree/main/src/lib/utils) folder and [vue3-tree/src/lib/components/`Tree.vue`](https://github.com/wopehq/vue3-tree/blob/main/src/lib/components/Tree.vue) to clarify the problem yourself or write a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/wopehq/vue3-tree/issues), if you like to have it solved by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The 'node' parameter of `onNodeClick`  gets the node *as value*. So, if you change the `label`, then you change it in the local value copy of your node.

To change the `label` in the tree you have to write some function to iterate over the data tree, find the node and change the `label` directly.

Something like this:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    label: "Animal",
    nodes: [
      {
        id: 2,
        label: "Dog",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: "Cat",
        nodes: [
          {
            id: 4,
            label: "Egyptian Mau Cat",
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            label: "Japanese Bobtail Cat",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    label: "People",
  }
]

function changeLabel(nodeId, newLabel) {
  var nodes = [];
  for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    nodes.unshift(data[i]);
  }
  let found = false;
  while(!found || nodes.length == 0) {
    var node = nodes.shift();
     if (node.id == nodeId) {
      found = true;
      node.label = newLabel;      
    }
    if (node.nodes != undefined && node.nodes.length > 0) {
      node.nodes.forEach((item) => {nodes.unshift(item)});
    }
  }  
}

changeLabel(5, "!!!New Label!!!");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Isn't there some way of adding ref to make it a call by reference?

Comment: The source code of the library can answer all questions. ;-)